# VBA Convert String to Logic Sequence

Tags: string, vba, excel, logic

I am working with a database export with the following type of information:

```
TestID  | Logic                      | Criterion_1 | Criterion_2 | ... | Criterion N
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101     | 1 AND 2                    | Apple       | California  | ... | Space Quest 6
102     | (1 OR 2) AND (3 OR 5 OR 6) | Banana      | New Jersey  | ... | Scorched Earth
```

My program would then compare this to some data and see if criteria match the data in some pattern that satisfies the logic. In my ideal world, I could take the Logic string and replace the numbers with tests:

```
(DataElement_1 = Criterion_1) AND (DataElement_2 = Criterion_2)
```

for Test 101. Of course, simply replacing pieces like that does not logic make. Is there some way in VBA to evaluate that as though it were in-code logic? Is there, perhaps, a better way of doing this that I have completely overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: If you believe my solution or other ones are helpful feel free to upvote and/or mark as *the answer*. <rant> Answerers are people just like you but when they'll need answers they usually have to place bounties. </rant>

Comment: I would love to upvote or place bounties, but I lack the reputation to do so. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub ert()
LastRow = Worksheets("data").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'finds the last row with data on the "data" sheet
For i = 1 To LastRow 'for each row
    evalstr = "=" & Cells(i, 2).Value 'creates a function from the statement in column "B" 
    evalstr = Replace(evalstr, "AND", "*") 'replaces the "AND" operator with a logical multiplication 
    evalstr = Replace(evalstr, "OR", "+") 'replaces the "OR" operator with a logical addition
    For j = 1 To 7 'for each condition
         evalstr = Replace(evalstr, CStr(j), Cells(i, 2 + j).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Criterion_" & j).RefersToRange.Value) 'replace the reference with the applicable evaluation
    Next
    Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 10) = evalstr 'inserts the formula to your "J" column
Next
End Sub
```

Works fine on my [test worksheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-773Ttgo1z6UThSaFlrVndRWlk/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Oh, that's very clever! I like it a lot!